# embed domain.php in html

Tags: php, html, embed

I wanted to ask you if there is a way to embed a .php in an HTML document.
the .php functions like an RSS feed. It's a job market feed from another page and I want to embed it into my page. I have control over the page where the job-feed is from. if I simply copy the code the feed doesn't refresh and keeps the same jobs.

please, help me!

its about this .php : https://www.jobverde.de/job_suche_extern.php

Comment: Rename the HTML file to .php (assuming the server it lives on can execute PHP). Or use an iframe to embed it maybe. There is more than one way. Do you have any preference? have you done any research?

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. the problem with iframe is, that it will open the links in the iframe window :/

Comment: Ok. I think you have to use my first suggestion then

Comment: okay i will! and how do i embed it in a wordpress page?

Comment: Huh? You said you wanted to embed it a HTML page, not a Wordpress site. Wordpress is already based on PHP so you won't have the same problem. But _integrating it_ into Wordpress's more complex environment might make things interesting. It depends on the detailed specifics, which we don't have access to here.

Comment: yes the thing is i want to embed it in a HTML page and a wordpress page... what specifics you would need to know?

Comment: Pretty much everything about the wordpress page and the PHP code you want to embed.The potential for conflicts and niggles would be endless, I suspect, depending on exactly those two bits of code do, and how complex they are. or it could be really straightforward. Anyway it sounds like a separate question - integrating into a simple HTML page and a wordpress site are two very different use cases.